# What encoding does python 2.7's unicode literal expect?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Okay. So I have a library that's giving me a value like this:

```
>>> x
'ADC (10^-6 mm\xb2/s):Sep 05 2017 11-58-19 CDT'
>>> type(x)
str
>>> print(x)
ADC (10^-6 mm?/s):Sep 05 2017 11-58-19 CDT
```

It's not ascii, and it doesn't appear to be UTF-8 either:

```
>>> x.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 13: invalid start byte
```

and I can't just convert it:

```
>>> y = unicode(x)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But I can do this, with straight-up copy and paste:

```
>>> y = u'ADC (10^-6 mm\xb2/s):Sep 05 2017 11-58-19 CDT'
>>> type(y)
unicode
>>> y.encode('utf-8')
'ADC (10^-6 mm\xc2\xb2/s):Sep 05 2017 11-58-19 CDT'
>>> print(y)
ADC (10^-6 mm²/s):Sep 05 2017 11-58-19 CDT
```

I want to turn `x` into type `unicode`. Assigning the value as a literal works for some reason. Is there some way to use the same rules for literal assignment to decode my `x`?

Sorry. I know I'm missing something super basic here.

Comment: `x.decode('latin1')`. (See [PEP-263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the library is giving you strings in the latin-1 encoding (or possibly code page 1252). This is annoying, isn't it... you have to guess what the correct encoding is! (This is one of the motivating factors for Python 3.)

```
y = x.decode('latin-1')
```

Note that in latin-1, `'\xb2'` becomes `u'\xb2'` when decoded. This is true for all latin-1 characters, since the bottom 256 code points for Unicode are the same as latin-1.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I thought latin-1 and ascii were identical encodings.

Comment: Thinking about this more: why does `x = u'\xb2'` work? sys.getdefaultencoding() is ascii, sys.stdin.encoding is utf-8. Not a latin-1 or 8859 in there so why does it try that encoding?

Comment: @Nate: Encoding doesn't matter here. `u'\xb2'` is a Unicode string, it is *not* encoded (well, technically it is, but the encoding is a technical detail hidden in the implementation of the `unicode` class). It's the same as `u'\u00b2'`, or `unichr(0xb2)`, or however you want to specify "a Unicode string containing the character U+00B2".

Comment: Or what I should say is that it appears as ASCII in the source code, so the encoding of the source code doesn't matter.

Comment: Aaaaaahhhhhhhh that makes sense. I would have thought I needed to actually say \u00b2 if I wanted a unicode char, and that \xb2 would be, y'know, a byte value that required an encoding. Thanks!